# pandas - get differ between two data frame with same dimensions

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can I get the differ between two pandas dataframe with the same dimensions:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'y': [1,    1,   1,   1,   1],
    'z': [2,    2,   2,   2,   2]})
print(df1)
  
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'y': [1,    1,   1,   1,   1],
    'z': [3,    3,   3,   3,   3]})

print(df2)
```

I would like the output delta data frame is:

```
   x  y  z
0  a  0  1
1  b  0  1
2  c  0  1
3  d  0  1
4  e  0  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `x` as the common index, subtract and reset the index (pandas aligns on the index before any operation):

```
df2.set_index('x').sub(df1.set_index('x')).reset_index()
 
   x  y  z
0  a  0  1
1  b  0  1
2  c  0  1
3  d  0  1
4  e  0  1
```